# R: How to terminate parallel computing when any error occurs to a node?

Tags: r, debugging, error-handling, parallel-processing

In R, I use `parallel` or `parallelMap` packages to perform parallel computing on Windows machine.

However, it is very time-consuming to wait for computation-intensive work, especially when an error occurs to a node but the whole parallel computing still continues until all iterations are finished, only to report that thousands of errors have occurred, and no meaningful results yield.

How should I terminate parallel computing as soon as any error occurs to any node?